# UserControl-Style for disabled state will not be applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

After having some problems with applying a "Control-Disabled-Style" to my usercontrol I stumbled over another problem.

As you can see there are two predefined gradients for `IsEnabled == true` and `IsEnabled == false`.
Now if I disable my usercontrol the gradient for the disabled state will not be applied. I do not know why but nothing happens. The Control will just look the same as if it is enabled.
I created some other UserControls and let them change their colour if disabled - and it worked.

I cannot find any errors maybe you could help me?

Source:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalStateGradient" EndPoint="1.197,0.542" StartPoint="0.037,0.542">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF4D4D4D" Offset="0.741"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#29000000" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DisabledStateGradient" EndPoint="1.197,0.542" StartPoint="0.037,0.542">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0000" Offset="0.741"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#29000000" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonEnableStates" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalStateGradient}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledStateGradient}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonEnableStates}" />
```

Comment: This code works fine -- if you set the *LayoutRoot* to have *IsEnabled=false*, it shows the disabled (red) gradient.  Could you show the rest of your code, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. i just got the problem. I forgot to put this version of the control to the application (had another version with a different name). Thought that the version was updated -.-'